Custom backend for Python Social Auth encounters error saying "issubclass() arg 1 must be a class"
I'm attempting to create a custom backend (Ping Identity) in Python Social Auth for a Django project following these directions: https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/implementation.html. I've tried using my own custom backend for Ping Identity and the GitHubOAuth2 example that is found within the documentation, but I keep getting an error saying "issubclass() arg 1 must be a class". Below is the full trace.
When I step through the code it seems that PSA thinks my custom class is not a subclass of BaseAuth. This check is found in social_core/backends/utils line 35:
if issubclass(backend, BaseAuth):
    BACKENDSCACHE[backend.name] = backend

My Ping Identity code looks pretty much the same as the example in the documentation, so lets look at that code:
from social_core.backends.oauth import BaseOAuth2

class GitHubOAuth2(BaseOAuth2):
    """GitHub OAuth authentication backend"""
    name = 'github'
    AUTHORIZATION_URL = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize'
    ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token'
    ACCESS_TOKEN_METHOD = 'POST'
    SCOPE_SEPARATOR = ','
    EXTRA_DATA = [
        ('id', 'id'),
        ('expires', 'expires')
    ]

    def get_user_details(self, response):
        """Return user details from GitHub account"""
        return {'username': response.get('login'),
                'email': response.get('email') or '',
                'first_name': response.get('name')}

    def user_data(self, access_token, *args, **kwargs):
        """Loads user data from service"""
        url = 'https://api.github.com/user?' + urlencode({
            'access_token': access_token
        })
        return self.get_json(url)

The class uses BaseOAuth2 -> OAuthAuth -> BaseAuth, so I'm not sure why PSA is complaining. My settings.py (project_name.project_name.settings) looks like this:
...
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'api.PingIdentityOAuth2',
    'api.GitHubOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
...

The GitHubOAuth2 example file is project_name.api.GitHubOAuth2. I test this by just doing a GET request to localhost:8000/login/github or localhost:8000/login/pingidentity.
I debugged the code and can confirm it seems to grab the correct class when it does the issubclass(backend, BaseAuth):. Just to be sure, I did an import on the custom class in my View to see if it was a path issue and that seemed fine. I also checked some of the Github and stackoverflow issues, but didn't see anything that matched my issue. Any suggestions for this one?
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/login/github/

Django Version: 5.0.6
Python Version: 3.10.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'corsheaders',
 'social_django',
 'api.apps.ApiConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/projects/project_name/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/social_core/backends/utils.py", line 49, in get_backend
    return BACKENDSCACHE[name]

During handling of the above exception ('github'), another exception occurred:
  File "/home/username/projects/project_name/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/username/projects/project_name/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/username/projects/project_name/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 80, in _view_wrapper
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/projects/project_name/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/social_django/utils.py", line 63, in wrapper
    return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/projects/project_name/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/social_django/utils.py", line 44, in wrapper
    request.backend = load_backend(
  File "/home/username/projects/project_name/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/social_django/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
    return strategy.get_backend(name, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
  File "/home/username/projects/project_name/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/social_core/strategy.py", line 176, in get_backend
    Backend = self.get_backend_class(name)
  File "/home/username/projects/project_name/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/social_core/strategy.py", line 172, in get_backend_class
    return get_backend(self.get_backends(), name)
  File "/home/username/projects/project_name/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/social_core/backends/utils.py", line 52, in get_backend
    load_backends(backends, force_load=True)
  File "/home/username/projects/project_name/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/social_core/backends/utils.py", line 35, in load_backends
    if issubclass(backend, BaseAuth):

Exception Type: TypeError at /login/github/
Exception Value: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class


Please, [edit] the question and share the full traceback as code (not an image). Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.

@willeM_VanOnsem added the trace at the bottom.
